# karma config with browserify/babel

Tags: karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I have a karma conf that I try to make work with babel/browserify. It looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-babel-preprocessor',
        'karma-browserify'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        '../src/**/*.js': ['babel', 'browserify'],
        'unit/*.spec.js': ['babel', 'browserify']
    },
    files: [
        '../src/**/*.js',
        'unit/*.spec.js'
    ],
    babelPreprocessor: {
        options: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            sourceMap: 'inline'
        },
        filename: function (file) {
            return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
        },
        sourceFileName: function (file) {
            return file.originalPath;
        }
    }
});
```

};

Every time I run this configuration through gulp babel preprocessor returns the following error: 
ERROR [preprocessor.babel]: Cannot read property 'bundleFile' of undefined

Comment: Never mind. Fixed it by removing babel and adding transforms for browserify

Comment: do you mind adding your fixed karma.conf file?

Comment: Please add the updated karma.conf file for others that are having this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding 'browserify' to 'frameworks', like this:
`frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine']`

I had the same error, fixed by doing this. Here's my working karma config

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: true,
        frameworks: ['browserify', 'mocha'],
        reporters: ['dots'],
        files: ['./*test.js'],
        preprocessors: {
            '*.js': ['browserify']
        },
        logLevel: 'LOG_DEBUG',
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [ ['babelify', {presets: ['es2015', "react"]} ] ]
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The fixed config file:

`module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
        plugins: [
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-babel-preprocessor',
            'karma-browserify'
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            '../src/js/app.js': ['browserify'],
            '../src/js/login/login-ctrl.js': ['browserify'],
            './unit/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
        },
        files: [
            '../../node_modules/angular/angular.js',
            '../../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '../src/js/app.js',
            '../dist/js/partials/templates-all.js',
            '../src/js/login/login-ctrl.js',
            'unit/*.spec.js'
        ],
        browserify: {
            debug: true,
            transform: [
                ['babelify']
            ]
        },
        singleRun: false,
        reporters: ['progress'],
        colors: true
    });
};`